# Will restoring inheritance on a given list restore all permissions on items too?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, inheritance, item-level-permissions

If I with CSOM restore inheritance on a given list, will it then restore all permissions on all items in the list? So there will be no more unique permissions on any items? Or do I have to restore inheritance on each item in the list?

```
list.ResetRoleInheritance();
```

vs

```
var items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in items)
{
   item.ResetRoleInheritance();
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: The second option. It only resets role inheritance on the object you have loaded.